# How to make a robot arm move in gazebo with ROS 1?

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

For a school project I want to move [this](https://www.trossenrobotics.com/p/phantomx-ax-12-reactor-robot-arm.aspx)
robot arm in gazebo with ros. I already can load in the robotarm model with roslaunch and start gazebo and move the joints in gazebo, but I don't know exactly how I can move this robot arm with ros and use cpp code. I also can't really find any good tutorials. Can somebody please help me? If you know some good tutorials let me know.

I use this

ubuntu 20.04 LTS

ROS 1 noetic

gazebo 11.9.1

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/393315/how-to-make-a-robot-arm-move-in-gazebo-with-ros-1?/) by [abracadabra](https://answers.ros.org/users/92077/abracadabra/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2021-12-24

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi @abracadabra,

I suggest this book: `Mastering ROS for Robotics Programming Third Edition` by Lentin Joseph and Jonathan Cacace. Chapter 3 and 4 are step by step of what you are looking to set up the robot arm in Gazebo first but it looks you have done this step. However it's critical as the other steps build on that.

Check this tutorial to connect to a robot arm with C++: https://community.arm.com/arm-research/b/articles/posts/do-you-want-to-build-a-robot

I also suggest you look into `MoveIt` as it's many great examples and there is a tutorial how to integrate with Gazebo: https://ros-planning.github.io/moveit_tutorials/doc/gazebo_simulation/gazebo_simulation.html

---

Originally posted by [osilva](https://answers.ros.org/users/84086/osilva/) with karma: 1650 on 2021-12-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0